# Everything moves in website when changed from full screen mode on desktop screen

Tags: html, css, web

Right now my code for my screen looks perfect, but for some reason everytime I change to browser size from full screen to a smaller window all my nav bar moves underneath eachother under the header div and other things as well. If I was to add things in the footer as well how can I set it up so that the page stays the same no matter how you resize it. I don't mind if its fixed on only a full screen mode.

Another issue is that when I asked a friend to check the websites on his laptop it was all messed up because of screen resolution I think, but when I saw it on my monitor it looked completely fine. So I am confused and have no idea how to fix this issue. I have researched as much as I can, but everything I tried didn't work.

So all I am trying to do is make sure that the website is fixed and is only viewable in full screen. If I resize it to smaller then you can't see parts of the page and that's all.

If you could please help me that would be great!

http://jsfiddle.net/thNRs/   ---------------->JSFIDDLE DEMO. You can see the problem right away using this.

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
<div id="page">

        <div id="header">
                <a href="http://wireless.fm.intel.com/test/index.php"><img src="http://wireless.fm.intel.com/test/logo2.png" border=0></a>
                <h2><a href="http://moss.ger.ith.intel.com/sites/MWG-IS/Pages/Default.aspx" border=0>Mobility Group</a></h2>

                <div id="navigation">
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                        <a href="#">Reports</a>
                        <a href="#">Documents</a>
                        <a href="#">Checklists</a>
                        <a href="#">License Tools</a>
                        <a href="#">Presentations</a>
                        <a href="#">Software Releases</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main"></div>

        <div id="footer">
                <!--<h4>WNG Product Development Engineering (US)</h4>
                <a href="https://employeeportal.intel.com/irj/portal">Circuit</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>-->
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS CODE:

```
html, body
{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
}
#page
{
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
}
#header
{
        background-color:#115EA2;
        height:100px;
        width:97.5;
        position:relative;
}
#main
{
        width:1300px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#F1F2F3;
        min-height:90%;
        height:auto;
        height:89%;
        margin:0 auto -50px;
        vertical-align:bottom;
}
#footer
{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0;
        height:35px;
        background-color: #115EA2;
}
#header img
{
        float:left;
        display:inline;
}
#header h2
{
        text-align:center;
        font-size:44px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        left:0px;
        top:20px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family: Sans-serif;
        float:left;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-left:20px;
        text-decoration:none;
}
#header h2, a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
}
/*#footer h4
{
        left:20px;
        top:-10px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family: Sans-serif;
        float:left;
        color:#fff;
        margin-left:20px;
}
#footer a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{
        color::#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
        position:relative;
        left:1025px;
        top:10px;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family:Sans-serif;
        float:left;
        margin-left:20px;
}*/
/* NAVIGATION BAR CODE */
#navigation
{
        position:absolute;
        top:60;
        left:500;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        width:60%;
        height:24px;
        background-color:#115EA2;
        min-width:100px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px 20px;
}
#navigation a
{
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-style:Sans-serif;
        margin:10px 0;
        height:18px;
        padding:12px 10px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-decoration:none;
}
#navigation a:hover
{
        background-color:#333;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** - or Demo please....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thNRs/  This is in JSFiddle. That is not how it looks on my screen when in full screen mode. So you can see the problem right away when you see it in this demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution to problems with the page shifting when the window resizes or when someone does a ctrl + mouse wheel up/down type of page zoom is to set sizes of things on the page using the em unit.  For example:

```
height:12.5em;
```

not...

```
height:200px;
width:60%;
```

etc...

1em == 16px by default.  If you change the font size to a new em I think it can mess things up so as long as you're not doing that you're fine.

Set all containers **except for** the outermost containers to a definite size and use em units as they are calculated based on the font size or something so when you zoom the page everything stays the same relative size and you don't get messes.  When I say outermost container I am referring to the ones directly inside the main tags, body, header, etc... set those with:

```
margin:auto;
width:(desired)%;
```

because they are on the outside, they only change in reference to the edge of the display area so when you zoom in and out, the outer edge buffer of the page just collapses and the things in the center appear to shrink and enlarge from the center.

So get a calculator, and start converting things like width:1300px; to width:81.25em.

One last note.  em units round to 3 decimal places. ie. 2px = .125em exactly but 1px =/= .0625em  you would use .063em.

Comment: So I have a Wrapper Div and in that I have Header Main and Footer. So you want me to change the height of all of those from the height of px I have set to em? Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes, everything but the outermost containers that have no content outside of them.  The the html tag area that is holding the three divs you just listed is the holder of the outermost containers.  Those 3 divs can have width set to a percentage because the only thing they are relative to is the edge of the window or monitor.  If you use px and you do zooming, your aspect ratios change, but in em, it recalculates the sizes so that they keep all of the same ratios.  Pretty much everything else should have a defined height/width in css so that it doesn't just 100% width everything by default.

Comment: I also notice that you are using ids for your css.  This is not recommended.

Comment: I read in another comment you wrote that you want the links to the right of the logo/name.  Don't use float and display together.  I would recommend display:inline-block; for your header.  IMPORTANT: if you do not set a size for EACH ELEMENT they will fill the ENTIRE width of their parent, thus, starting a new row!!! float:left also fixes this, but it isn't doing what you think it is!  Float: = "abandon all hope ye who enter here" IMHO.  There are some special cases when I would use it and that's beyond ?'s scope

Comment: If I remember correctly, float is even capable of breaking the stability provided by using the em unit.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. I have been trying to figure out this issue before I replied based on your answers. I understand what you are saying. I just am not able to figure out to convert from px to em for all the height in #page, #header, #main, and #footer. I am so lost now on converting. Also I thought you use ID's when you have a certain one thing to change and not multiple things you need to use. Isnt that correct?

Comment: Also if you are saying that we arent supposed to use float. Then how do I have it set so that The logo is first then the title "Mobility Group" is second and the third is the navigation bar and so that it doesn't overflow to a new row. @unipartisandev

Comment: 1em is 16 px.  That is the conversion.  When height/width  is a percentage, it is a percentage of the parent container. Use an id for something unique such as a username input field in a login form.  There would only ever be one of those, right?  The password input field would also have an id.  It's not that you can't do it.  Your nav buttons would be a great example of a class.  so .navbutton would apply to each button rather than making an id with its own properties for each button.

Comment: The way to make the logo, mobility group, and the nav buttons line up in a row is first to make sure that that is the order in which they appear in the HTML.  Set them to display:inline-block; in your CSS.  Here is the "gotcha": you must declare a width for every item. If you do not specify width, then width is 100% by default which means that every element will fill the entire horizontal width and force the next element to a new row.  Float is something else.  What float does not do is tell the elements what order they're supposed to be in.  What it tell them is...

Comment: ... stack up against eachother with no margin from the left/right. Until all horiozontal space is filled and all vertical space of the previous element is filled. by the next ones.  So write the html for your logo, set it to display:inline-block;  then do mobility group the same and make sure you define their widths. CSS does not know to do an automatic "skin-tight" fit on the elements.  You have to do that yourself.  Then your nav buttons: give them a class, not an id. Give the class the width you want each button to be and make them display:inline-block; Same for their parent container. GL!

Answer (score 0):

[Something to this effect?](http://jsfiddle.net/thNRs/1/)

The biggest issue was that you didn't have a minimum width for your menu, so it would keep shrinking until it stacked on itself.

```
 #navigation {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    height:24px;
    min-width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that is not exactly how I wanted it. I wanted the Mobility group right next to the logo and then the tabs just to the right of mobility group at the bottom of the header going all the way to the end of the header.

Comment: To be honest though I don't mind your design. Maybe if move Mobility Group to the top and the tabs for the navigation bar beneath the Intel Logo and Mobility Group. That would work pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

Add fix width to the #navigation. It has percent value now, so its width will counted from the body's width (60%).
If the #navigation's width narrower than the elements' width sum, the elements will start to fall to the second row.

The #header's width is "97.5".
Without measurement type (px, percent or some else) it will be ignored by the browsers (it will be 100%).

Comment: Ok I think i get what you are trying to say. So how would I make sure that it does not fall into the second row then and stay in the same place?